# How can i stream video using udpsrc pipeline in QT

Tags: c++, qt, video, udp, gstreamer

Server Windows:

```
gst-launch-1.0.exe videotestsrc ! rtpvraewpay ! udpsink host=192.168.101.111 port=8001
```

Client Linux:

I use following pipeline and i can display testvideosrc video:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)RAW,width=(string)480,height=(string)360,payload=(int)96" port=8001 ! rtpvrawdepay ! videoconvert ! glimagesink
```

But i cant display testvideo on QWidget with following c++ code:

```
ScreenWidgets.append(new CamWidget(this));
ui->gridLayout_screens->addWidget(ScreenWidgets.last());

WId windowId= ScreenWidgets.last()->winId();

GtElement *pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("udp_pipeline");
GstElement *source        = gst_element_factory_make("udpsrc","source");
GstElement *depayloader   = gst_element_factory_make("rtpvrawdepay","depayl");
GstElement *q1          = gst_element_factory_make("queue", "qone1");
GstElement *convert1   = gst_element_factory_make("videoconvert","conv");
GstElement *q2          = gst_element_factory_make("queue", "q2");
GstElement *sink          = gst_element_factory_make("glimagesink","sink");

GstCaps *caps = gst_caps_new_simple("application/x-rtp",
                           "media", G_TYPE_STRING, "video",
                           "clock-rate",G_TYPE_INT,90000,
                           "encoding-name", G_TYPE_STRING,"RAW",
                           "width",G_TYPE_STRING,"640",
                           "height",G_TYPE_STRING,"480",
                           "payload",G_TYPE_INT,96,
                           NULL);


if(source != NULL && depayloader != NULL
   && convert1 != NULL && q1 && q2
   && sink!= NULL && caps != NULL)
{
    g_object_set(GST_OBJECT(sink),"sync",FALSE,NULL);
    g_object_set(GST_OBJECT(sink),"enable-last-sample",TRUE,NULL);

    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(source),"port",8001,NULL);
    //g_object_set(G_OBJECT(source),"buffer-size",640000,NULL);


    gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), source, depayloader, NULL);

    gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), convert1 ,q2, q1, sink, NULL);


    if(gst_element_link_many(depayloader,
                             q1,
                             convert1,
                             q2,
                             sink,
                             NULL))
    {
        if(gst_element_link_filtered(source,depayloader,caps))
        {
            gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle(GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY(sink),windowId);

            GThread *thread = g_thread_new(NULL,(GThreadFunc)func,loop);
        }
     }
}
```

Can anyone help me where is my wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add any error output, it will help those viewing your question to find an answer. Note you will need to run your program from command line.

Comment: Hi, I don't give any error but also i cant display video. I use for development QT IDE.

Comment: I have not worked with this IDE. The IDE may or may not capture stderr from the script when it is running - or there may be a special 'console' window where it shows text output from the script. If you have that option, do run the program from command line, this is guaranteed to get you the stdout/stderr messages. As far as I remember gstreamer is quite verbose on those, there is a good chance you will see some clue, even if there is no actual error message.

Answer (score 0):

Creating pipeline using gst_parse_launch(), worked for me.

```
GstElement *pipeline_2= gst_parse_launch("udpsrc port=20000 ! application/x-rtp,encoding-name=JPEG,payload=26 ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegparse ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! ximagesink  name=mySink", NULL);

GstElement *sink = gst_bin_get_by_name((GstBin*)pipeline_2,"mySink");

QWidget *window = new QWidget();
window->setWindowTitle("udpsrc video stream");
window->resize(700, 700);

WId xwinid = window->winId();
gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle (GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY (sink), (guintptr)xwinid);

window->show();
GstStateChangeReturn sret = gst_element_set_state (pipeline_2, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
```

Hope this helps.